# Сравнение двух переменных Extended c заданной точностью в Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-tokyo

В связи с тем что в коде после вычислений мне необходимо часто округлять (до определенного разряда после запятой), а затем сравнивать вещественные величины, хотелось бы понять, как наиболее правильно это делать. Как известно из-за представления дробей в двоичном виде, в переменной может оказаться величина которую мы туда передали с некоторой погрешностью. Поэтому нельзя напрямую сравнивать вещественные переменные данным образом

```
if ExtendedVar1 <= ExtendedVar2 then....
```

Но `CompareValue` к сожалению мне так же не подходит, например для такого случая:

```
ExtendedVar1 := DecimalRoundExt(...., 8, drHalfUp);
ExtendedVar2 := DecimalRoundExt(...., 8, drHalfUp);
```

Для арифметического округления использую библиотеку от John Herbster, после которого предполагается что `ExtendedVar1` принимает значение `0.00000006` а `ExtendedVar2` - `0.00000007`.

Опять же, из-за двоичного представления дробей `CompareValue(E2, E1, 1E-8)` возвратит `0`, что по нашей логике неверно.

Из этого напрашивается сравнение непосредственно при округлении:

```
ExtendedVar1 := .... ; //вычисления
ExtendedVar2 := .... ;

if DecimalRoundExt(ExtendedVar2, 8, drHalfUp) >= DecimalRoundExt(ExtendedVar1, 8, drHalfUp) then ....
```

Но на сколько это правильно, не хранит ли такое сравнение подводные камни, которые  не очевидны на первый взгляд? И есть ли вариант получше?

Comment: Нужно точно понять, что вам реально требуется. Например, округление "до скольки-то знаков" в большинстве случаев особого смысла не имеет (к выводу это не относится). Например, не будет ли правильно  в вашем случае работать с фиксированной точкой?

Comment: @MBo реально нам требует сравнивать результаты вычислений вещественного типа, округленные "до стольки-то знаков". Степень округления в нашем случае, величина не постоянная.

Comment: Ох, боюсь, что `сравнивать результаты вычислений вещественного типа, округленные "до стольки-то знаков"` - это может быть вашей интерпретацией реальной проблемы. Вы осознаёте, что числа `0.00000006` на самом деле в памяти не существует?

Comment: @MBo осознаю, об этом написано в моем посте.

Comment: А сравнивать используя динамический коэффициент (`SameValue(a, b)` без ручного задания `epsilon`), до округления, не вариант?

Comment: ОК, что вы хотите получить при сравнении этих величин? Можно их вычесть, опять же округлить и смотреть на округленную разницу. Будет ли это полезно?  И как насчёт фиксированной точки?

Comment: @MBo В идеале, хотелось бы избавиться от погрешностей вещественного типа при работе с малыми величинами (от -6 до -12 степени разрядности) и иметь обычное арифметическое округление для сравнения результатов друг с другом или некоторыми контрольными величинами. Что вы имеете в виду под фиксированной точкой, повысив разрядность до нужной степени приводить данные к целочисленному типу?

Comment: @MBo если я правильно понял, в варианте с вычислением разницы, округленный результат опять придется сравнивать, опять упираемся на те же грабли?

Comment: @zed мне нужно сравнение чисел с определенной точностью, не уверен что динамический коэф. для каждого случая всегда будет рассчитываться именно таким какой нужен.

Comment: Если величины близкого порядка, то умножить всё на 10^14 (чуть больше,чем минимальный порядок разрядности), допустим, и работать с Int64. Про округление разницы - не исключено. Но почему вы разницу величин минус восьмого порядка сравниваете с допуском того же порядка? Заметьте, что многие функции сравнения нормируют допуск на порядок величин - те же CompareValue и SameValue, если Eps нулевой, как указал zed уже.

Comment: @MBo если работать с int64, тогда посоветуйте каким образом лучше округлять результаты вычислений например при делении? Уточню, нужно именно арифметическое округление, стандартный Round не подходит.

Comment: Имеется в виду округление x.5 к большему? `(intvalue + 5*10) div 100 * 100`

Comment: @MBo Да, x.5 к большему. Только ваш пример не понял. Допустим результатом деления двух целых чисел является дробное, т.е. его нужно округлить и так же привести к целочисленному типу. Я вижу это так: `Int3 := Int1 div Int2; if 2*(Int1 mod Int2) >= Int2 then inc(Int3);`

Comment: Да, всё  верно..